# integration of open cv with tensorflow in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow

I managed to put OpenCv and and Tensorflow together in one program using cmake, everything worked fine when I was just loading a png image from disk, converting from Mat to Tensor and then doing classification.

But then when I changed the source to live image from camera the input is just black picture. I then started checking which Tensorflow includes are causing issues and got down to these two: "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h" and "tensorflow/core/public/session.h". I can add 10 other tensorflow libraries (was about 12 in example) and image coming from camera is still fine, but as soon as I add any of these two it gets black again. Here I wasn't calling any tensorflow functions, just trying to figure if include itself is the problem.

Anyone has any idea what might be causing the issue? Thanks in advance

Edit

This code compiles fine and the camera input works fine

```
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/core/threadpool.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/io/path.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/strings/stringprintf.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/init_main.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/logging.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/types.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/command_line_flags.h"

#include    <iostream>
#include    "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include    "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        cv::VideoCapture capture;
        if(!capture.open(0))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        cv::Mat frameCam;
        capture >> frameCam;
        if( frameCam.empty() )
        {
            std::cerr << "error";
        }

        cv::namedWindow("Camera Image",cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        while(1)
        {
            capture >> frameCam;
            cv::imshow("Camera Image",frameCam);
            char c = (char)cv::waitKey(10);
            if(c == 27)
                break;
        }
        return  0;
}
```

CMakeLists (based on [This](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc/tree/tf-1.3.0))

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3 FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable(example example.cpp)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( example ${OpenCV_LIBS})

find_package(TensorflowCC COMPONENTS Shared)
if(TensorflowCC_Shared_FOUND)
  target_link_libraries(example TensorflowCC::Shared)
# fallback to the static library
else()
  find_package(TensorflowCC REQUIRED COMPONENTS Static)
  target_link_libraries(example TensorflowCC::Static)
endif()
```

But when I add `#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"` or `#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"` the camera input stops working(the image is black). All of these libraries are used in [Tensorflow Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc) and this program also works fine. After some changes to it I was able to read .png file with OpenCV and process it thgrough Tensorflow, but when I tried the camera image was black so I started taking it into parts.. Thanks

Comment: Sample code and MWE (Minimum Working example) please.

Comment: Sorry, added it now. Hope you might know what the problem is. I'm recompilling the Tensorflow from scratch because I couldn't figure what's going on..